# Do 'vacuous' equations have infinte solutions or no solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logic

[edit: redacted the calculus of variations motivation as it is flawed. The logical question remains!]
<s>*This is is a general question (motivated by a calculus of variations problem) about the meaning of 'has a solution' for ODEs where the coefficients are 0! However, if I've missed something in the calculus of variations that invalidates my question please do comment.*</s>

Consider the following calculus of variations problem:

> Prove that for a variational problem with Lagrangian $F(x, y')$ (i.e. independent of y), the Jacobi accessory equation (in $h$)
> $$\frac{d}{dx}(F_{yy'}h + F_{y'y'}h') - F_{yy}h - F_{yy'}h' = 0$$
> has no non-trivial solutions for a minimiser $y_0$.

The gist of a proof I've been shown for this is that for the minimiser $y_0$, the Euler-Lagrange equation asserts that $F_{y'} = c$ [edit: at $y_0$!], and thus the Jacobi equation has all terms equal to zero. As a result, the equation is 0 = 0 and thus has 'no solutions'.

My question is, is this true? More simply if we have an equation like
$cf = 0$ where $c = 0$, one could argue that any $f$ is a solution as the equation holds for any sufficiently well-behaved function. But I understand that one could say there are no solutions as there is nothing to solve (or at least, no candidates for a solution). Do these problems have any admissible function as a solution, or no solutions at all?

Comment: It's not true, in general, that all terms of the Jacobi equation are equal to zero if $F_y=0$. For instance, if $F(x,y')=f(x)y'^2$, then $F_{y'y'}=2f(x)$ and Jacobi equation is given by $\frac{d}{dx}(2f(x)h')=0$.

Comment: @Gonçalo thank you for your comment and counter example! but by the Euler-Lagrange equation we have that for a minimiser with $F_y = 0$, $\frac{d}{dx} F_{y'} = 0$ and so $F_{y'}$ is constant, so $F_{y'y'}$ must be zero unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: nevermind, realised my mistake - was evaluating and differentiating in the wrong order. will redact the motivation and just leave the logic question!

Comment: I choose the first one.  If $c=0$ then every $f$ is a solution of $cf=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce complications, I'm going to talk about the simpler problem of finding the maximum of a function $f: [a,b]  \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

We have the basic theorem that if a function is differentiable at an interior point $c \in (a,b)$, and has a local maximum there, then $f'(c) = 0$. Let's apply it to $f(x) = x - x^2$ on $[0,1]$. We jump to finding $f'(x) = 1 - 2x$ and find its zero at $x=1/2$. But let's think about what the theorem lets us do: It doesn't say that the maximum is at $1/2$; what it does is rule out any  interior point other than $1/2$  from being the location of the maximum.

So after applying the theorem we know that we need only evaluate $f$ at the endpoints ($0$ and $1$) and at $1/2$ - those are the only possible locations for the maximum.

With that understanding in mind, let's now look at the trivial function $f(x) = 1$. If we go to solve $f'(x) = 0$, we're left looking at "$0=0$". And the results here are

- It has solutions. Lots of them. Any $x$ satisfies $f'(x) = 0$.
- However, our "find the maximum" theorem above has in some sense failed. The criterion it offers didn't allow us to remove any points from consideration as the location of a possible maximum.

I think when you're saying "there are no solutions as there is nothing to solve" that's what your trying to describe. But be aware that your language there is not accurate. There are solutions to your equation. There are in fact too many, and so your theorem failed, as it didn't reduce the set of possible solutions in this particular case.

Comment: This is fully analogous to the variational problem in $y_0$ and $h$. The criteria $f'=0$ and $f''>0$ cannot both be satisfied if $f'=0$ at every point on the whole interval

Comment: @Barri - I was hoping it was analogous enough to clarify the OP's. Glad for your comment that it is. (I'm just kinda weak on calculus of variation stuff.)

Comment: Thanks @JonathanZ, the least action principle is remarkably intuitive but yeah, the PDE equations that generalize a 'minimum' by introducing a perturbation are not trivial. I honestly just got into these problems recently, noticing how simple and elegant Noether's theorem is (it really boils down to $f'=0$ at an interior minimum), and how deep the implications

Answer (score 2):

Absent the context of the variational problem, then yes, trivially every admissible function is a solution when $c=0$. As the other answer explains in a generic setting, when finding a minimum the condition that there are too few restrictions on the solutions has a different interpretation.

There is 'no solution' to the variational problem you deleted in the sense that, there is no choice for $y_0$ that can be confirmed to be a minimizer (rather than, say, a maximum or saddle point curve) using the criteria that all nonzero solutions $h$ to the second order variation equation are strictly positive.

If a 'solution' is a valid restriction on $h$ (as a solution to the second order variational equation) that forces all nonzero $h$ to be strictly positive for all $x$, then it's clear that there is no such solution when the second derivative coefficients are all identically zero, except for $h=0$.